# Assigning structs

Tags: c

I have a struct like

```
struct T {
   int *baseofint
}Tstruct, *pTstruct;

int one;
pTstruct pointer;
```

now i want to define

```
one = pointer.baseofint; //got filled with an integer; 
error message: **operator is not equal to operand**
```

I also tried

```
one = *(pointer.baseofint);
error message:**operand of * is no pointer*
```

Maybe someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think the following code is what you think it is:

```
struct T {
   int *baseofint
}Tstruct, *pTstruct;

int one;
pTstruct pointer;
```

You're declaring a structure type `struct T`, and creating an instance of it called `Tstruct` and a pointer to it called `pTstruct`.  But those aren't types you're creating, they're variables.  That makes the `pTstruct pointer;` invalid code, too.  What you probably intended was a typedef:

```
typedef struct T {
  int *baseofint;
} Tstruct, *pTstruct;
```

...to make `Tstruct` equivalent to `struct T`, and `pTstruct` equivalent to `struct T *`.

As for accessing and dereferencing the `baseofint` field, it's slightly different depending on whether you're accessing it through a pointer or not... but here's how:

```
Tstruct ts;          // a Tstruct instance
pTstruct pts = &ts;  // a pTstruct -- being pointed at ts

/* ...some code that points ts.baseofint at
 *    an int or array of int goes here... */

/* with * operator... */
int one  = *(ts.baseofint);   // via struct, eg. a Tstruct
int oneb = *(pts->baseofint); // via pointer, eg. a pTstruct

/* with array brackets... */
int onec = ts.baseofint[0];   // via Tstruct
int oned = pts->baseofint[0]; // via pTstruct
```

Answer (score 1):

pTstruct is a pointer to a struct.  That struct contains a pointer to an int.  So you need to dereference them both.  Try:

```
*((*pointer).baseofint)
```

Also note

```
p->x
```

is an abbreviation of

```
(*p).x
```

so

```
*(pointer->baseofint)
```

is valid as well (and less difficult to read).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `*(pointer->baseofint)`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `*pointer->baseofint`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `->` to access a structure member through a pointer.  The following two expressions are equivalent:

```
pointer->baseofint
(*pointer).baseofint
```

In your case, you need to dereference `baseofint` as well:

```
one = *pointer->baseofint;
```

You've just hit on a great example of why it's a bad idea to hide the fact that a type is a pointer.

I guess that you're using a C++ compiler based on your code not having a `typedef` in it - you might end up causing yourself problems with that, too.